# set listview stackFromBottom programmatically

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a list which I want to change the items to be filled from the bottom pragmatically and not from the xml.

Is there a corresponding method for the attribute `android:stackFromBottom` ?

I want to set it true or false multiple times from the code.

Comment: May be [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2537110/2345913)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can do like this**

```
listView.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
listView.setStackFromBottom(true);
```