# ListView of WebViews does not scroll to bottom

Tags: android

I have a `ListView`.

Each item of the `ListView` is a small `WebView`.

I want my `ListView` to scroll to the bottom when the `ListView` is displayed.

But, alas, nothing seems to work:

```
lv.setTranscriptMode(ListView.TRANSCRIPT_MODE_ALWAYS_SCROLL);
mListView.setStackFromBottom(true);
```

No success.

```
myListView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
        myListView.setSelection(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
    }
});
```

No success.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2537110/2649012

Comment: @Vyger I have tried those, but no success

Answer (score 0):

Added the TouchListener in android listvieew each row webview.

```
mWebView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }
});
```