# Android Listview for Chat interface does not scroll

Tags: java, android, listview, chat

Im trying to build a chat app and although my listview does append a messages as they come in, I cannot access the messages that are older or hidden from the screen. The listview does not want to scroll and just display the amount of messages that fit onto the screen which are the most recent ones. It still does not work. Something to note i have a expanding toolbar and this layout is on a fragment

Edit: To fix this problem of the listview not scrolling add

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

to the listview that is not scrolling
Code:

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:weightSum="1"
android:background="@drawable/bg_messages">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view_messages"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:stackFromBottom="true"
    />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMsgCompose"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:orientation="horizontal"

    android:weightSum="3"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/inputMsg"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:paddingLeft="6dp"
        android:paddingRight="6dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:text="Send" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: by default we don't need any scroll for listview.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2537027/how-to-move-scroll-at-the-bottom-of-list-programmatically

Comment: the code is correct, I checked it, there is no problem with this code.

Comment: Yes, I did have the android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll" but that did not allow me to see the messages that were pushed of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

i might be think that weight is giving the problem here.I suggest that try to use RelativeLayout as your Parent Layout.Once just try to replace your Xml with this code below.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:background="@drawable/bg_messages">


<ListView
android:layout_above="@+id/llMsgCompose"
android:id="@+id/list_view_messages"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:divider="@null"
android:stackFromBottom="true"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
/>


<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/llMsgCompose"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:weightSum="3"   
>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/inputMsg"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:paddingLeft="6dp"
    android:paddingRight="6dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSend"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:text="Send" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Thanks, its Might be this help You.

Comment: It still does not work. Something to note i have a expanding toolbar and this layout is on a fragment.

Comment: are you adding any custom  view in   java?

Comment: No, all of the layouts are made with xml

Comment: i think xml is not the problem it is okky may be something wrong with the java

Comment: I have fixed it by allowing nested scrolling in my chat listview, but thank you everyone who has tried to help me solve the problem

Comment: @AbdulMirza Great at least you come back and share the answer.For the updating the answer one upvote for you